# eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: eieio-defclass-autoload

Tags: init-file, cedet

I'm played around with my `.emacs` and installed a few packages from melpa related to C++. Now when I start emacs, I get this error

```
eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: eieio-defclass-autoload
```

It doesn't happen with `emacs -Q`. So I completely emptied my `.emacs` and removed all packages I installed today. The error persists. I also use desktop sessions, so I turned this off with `emacs --no-desktop` but with no success. Which file is loaded that causes the error? Here is the complete `*messages*` buffer

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/preview-latex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Error while loading 50dictionaries-common: Symbol's value as variable is void: debian-aspell-only-dictionary-alist
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ess.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50global.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...done
eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: eieio-defclass-autoload
```

So I realized that `eieio` is part of cedet but didn't know how to get rid of it I guess since it's now included into `emacs`.

Comment: Did you try `--debu-init` when starting Emacs? This would give you the stack-trace for this problem. EIEIO is the object system, used by many packages other than CEDET (although it's part of the package). It would be difficult to guess who's doing that. the reason someone would be looking for this variable would be a definition s.a. `(defclass ...)`. Another way to identify the problem would be to try to byte-compile the *.el files that are being loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I ran `emacs --debug-init` and it pointed to the `helm-ls-git` package calling `eieio-defclass-autoload`. Removing `helm-ls-git` in the package manager solved the problem

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That worked (could not run Emacs 29.1 properly as it wouln't eval my init.el). Poinpointed an error loading helm-org-rifle. Commented that out, problem gone.